# Create list of list tuples from reading a txt file

Tags: python, file, nlp, token

I have a txt file that look likes

```
   EU NNP B-NP B-ORG
    rejects VBZ B-VP O
    German JJ B-NP B-MISC
    call NN I-NP O
    to TO B-VP O
    boycott VB I-VP O
    British JJ B-NP B-MISC
    lamb NN I-NP O
    . . O O
    
    Peter NNP B-NP B-PER
    Blackburn NNP I-NP I-PER

    BRUSSELS NNP B-NP B-LOC
    1996-08-22 CD I-NP O
```

And Im trying to make a tuples from this txt which ı will evalute them laterly word to features later on. I want to have a list of list look like this :

```
[(EU, NNP,B-NP, B-ORG),(rejects, VBZ, B-VP, O),(German, JJ, B-NP, B-MISC),(call, NN, I-NP, O).....
 (Peter, NNP, B-NP, B-PER),(Blackburn, NNP, I-N,P I-PER),
 (BRUSSELS, NNP, B-NP, B-LOC),(1996-08-22, CD, I-NP, O)
```

All of the whitespaces indicates that the sentences over and should add to list to given index, laterly after whitespace we should move on the next index of the list to add all sentences.

```
# function to read data, return list of tuples each tuple represents a token contains word, pos tag, chunk tag, and ner tag
import csv
def read_data(filename) -> list:
  data = []
  sentences = []
  with open(filename) as load_file:
    reader = csv.reader(load_file, delimiter=" ")   # read
   
    for row in reader:
      if(len(tuple(row)) != 0):
        data.append(tuple(row))
     
  sentences.append(data)
  return sentences
```

I have a function like this however it return this:

```
('EU', 'NNP', 'B-NP', 'B-ORG'),
  ('rejects', 'VBZ', 'B-VP', 'O'),
  ('German', 'JJ', 'B-NP', 'B-MISC'),
  ('call', 'NN', 'I-NP', 'O'),
  ('to', 'TO', 'B-VP', 'O'),
  ('boycott', 'VB', 'I-VP', 'O'),
  ('British', 'JJ', 'B-NP', 'B-MISC'),
  ('lamb', 'NN', 'I-NP', 'O'),
  ('.', '.', 'O', 'O'),
  ('Peter', 'NNP', 'B-NP', 'B-PER'),
  ('Blackburn', 'NNP', 'I-NP', 'I-PER'),
  ('BRUSSELS', 'NNP', 'B-NP', 'B-LOC'),
  ('1996-08-22', 'CD', 'I-NP', 'O'),
```

How can ı solve this problem, ı use 2 different list to add them together but ı could not find a way.

Comment: Isn't that output what you want? That looks like the desired output. What's wrong with it?

Comment: No actually for instance for first sentences which EU reject German call to boycott British lamb. should be in the first row, for second sentences Peter Blackburn should be in the second row. when ı see whitespace it should goes to other index. @EricJin

Comment: Does that mean you want a transposition, like `EU rejects German call to boycott British lamb` followed by `NNP VBZ JJ NN TO VB JJ NN`?

Comment: ı have word and their 3 different tags on their nearby. I want to keep them with the words, but instead ı need a build a list that first row contains given senteces with corresponding tags. I wrote how it should look like in the above, ı want to add words in to next word, not to downside, it should add down when we iterate next word

Comment: Wait, so you want to start a new list once you hit a blank line? Does the line need to be *completely* blank (or can it have some spaces)? csv format doesn't detect blank lines, so you'll need to parse the file manually.

Comment: @EricJin ı m reading txt file so ı think blank line is okay ı wrote them as whitespace but anyway, u are right it should compeltely blank and when ı hit that, ı should goves over to next sentences

Comment: You should always add `row` to `data` - and when you get empty line then add `data` to `sentences` and create new empty `data`

Comment: I think all problem it because you show wrong expected result. You show single list with tuples `[ tuple1, tuple2, ... ]` but you expecte list with sublists which have tuples `[ [tuple1, tuple2, ...],  [tuple11, tuple12, ...], ...]`

Comment: @furas yes ı think you are right but how can ı do that ı tried to do your idea, here is my code  for row in reader:
      data = []
      if(len(tuple(row)) != 0):
        data.append(tuple(row))
      else:
        sentences.append(data)
     
  
    return sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all problem is because you show expected result

```
[(EU, NNP,B-NP, B-ORG),(rejects, VBZ, B-VP, O),(German, JJ, B-NP, B-MISC),(call, NN, I-NP, O).....
 (Peter, NNP, B-NP, B-PER),(Blackburn, NNP, I-N,P I-PER),
 (BRUSSELS, NNP, B-NP, B-LOC),(1996-08-22, CD, I-NP, O)
```

but I think you expect

```
[
 [(EU, NNP,B-NP, B-ORG),(rejects, VBZ, B-VP, O),(German, JJ, B-NP, B-MISC),(call, NN, I-NP, O).....], 
 [(Peter, NNP, B-NP, B-PER),(Blackburn, NNP, I-N,P I-PER)],
 [(BRUSSELS, NNP, B-NP, B-LOC),(1996-08-22, CD, I-NP, O)],
]
```

and this need

```
    for row in reader:
        if row:
           data.append(tuple(row))
        else:
           sentences.append(data)
           data = []
```

At the end it may need also to add last `data` becuase there is no empty line after these data

```
    if data:
       sentences.append(data)
```

---

Full working example.

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory so everyone can copy and run it. But you should use `open()` without `text`.

```
text = '''EU NNP B-NP B-ORG
rejects VBZ B-VP O
German JJ B-NP B-MISC
call NN I-NP O
to TO B-VP O
boycott VB I-VP O
British JJ B-NP B-MISC
lamb NN I-NP O
. . O O

Peter NNP B-NP B-PER
Blackburn NNP I-NP I-PER

BRUSSELS NNP B-NP B-LOC
1996-08-22 CD I-NP O'''

import csv
import io

data = []
sentences = []

#with open(filename) as load_file:
with io.StringIO(text) as load_file:    
    reader = csv.reader(load_file, delimiter=" ")   # read
   
    for row in reader:
        if row:
           data.append(tuple(row))
        else:
           sentences.append(data)
           data = []

    # add last data because there is no empty line after these data           
    if data:
       sentences.append(data)

print(sentences)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! , it works well but ı did not understand why we add  the last if statement,

Comment: run my example code without this line and you will see different `sentences` - without last sentece. After last line there is NO empty line - so it will NOT run `else: sentences.append(data)` and you DON'T get last `data` in `sentence` - `[(BRUSSELS, NNP, B-NP, B-LOC),(1996-08-22, CD, I-NP, O)],` But if your have empty line at the end of your file then you don't need this `if` - but it is safer to use it because you may have file without empty line at the end.

Comment: BTW: you may use `print()` to see what you have in variables in different moments. It is called "print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.